# Applying migrations to a really out of sync database

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south, django-1.6

I've inherited a database that's in pretty bad shape. Basically the following:

- Most apps don't have a migrations folder or have an outdated one
- The south migration history table is out of sync with the database
- The database tables do not match up with the current models in Django (although I know what has changed between the models and tables)

I'm not worried about preserving past migration history or anything like that, but I do need to preserve the data currently in the database. I'm kind of looking for a way to declare the current database state the initial state and move forward from there. If necessary I can modify the models so that the database tables match the current models since I assume that is necessary to get started.

I've been messing around with this for a few hours, and I'd appreciate any advice for getting this straightened out.

Additional Notes:

- The database is using sqlite
- Moving to Django 1.8 is on the table but not for a few months

Comment: If moving to django 1.8 is on the cards, this is the time to bring it forward. Rest assured that moving from south to django migrations will bring up a few of it's own issues (though it's not supposed to). If you don't make the switch now, you will be fighting two battles instead of one

Comment: Matching your models with the current database state and then wiping/recreating the migrations should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions for django 1.6 with South

I would suggest downloading a dump of the database (or at the schema) and creating a new database with that on your local machine using sqllite.

Then delete all the existing `/migrations` folders in all of your apps
Then delete everything in in the database table `south_migrations`

Now disable all your 'new' model changes that aren't in the database

Then make the initial migrations again

`./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial`

Then fake it all, because the structure is already there
`./manage.py migrate --fake`

Now your migrations are in sync with your production database.

Now re-enable your new models changes then create the migrate each app
`./manage.py schemamigration myapp`

Then migrate to the new changes
`./manage.py migrate`

Note: on your server and dev machine you will need to ensure that you also delete the any old .pyc files inside the 'migrations' folders before creating any new migrations.

As per e4c5's comments above, you are going to have to do some of those steps again when you move to django 1.7/1.8 (as South got integrated into Django in 1.7), so you might want to consider upgrading to 1.7 at the same time (although thats not necessarily a trivial upgrade...).

Comment: Entity is supposed to simplify our development life not create a whole new set of issues. For a large biz where you may have created the database, but it now belongs to the DB Admins, updates & maintenance are done without your permission. Migrations become useless now and it becomes necessary to go DB 1st. Thus, my database development are in two separate projects. One for migrations as the project is created and another for Database first and application usage. This avoid issues like these then all I do is recreate the Entity in the DB 1st project. However, my projects are .Net

Comment: @Clarence Django is sort of built on the assumption that application controls schema. Schema is determined by the ORM. DBAs all work on the assumption that applications must follow the database schema. Building a DB in Django and then handing control to a DBA will be a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Neil I see your point, however, my comment is about the use of migrations and eliminating them in an Entity Framework .Net Environment. So IF SIMILAR to Django IN SOME WAY, my pov would be of service. Preparing for this by separating app development from DB development by eliminating migrations has been the key for me in .Net EF environment. In the real world, if your company's IT structure says hand off database operations to a DBA, you're going to hand it off despite your concerns about it being a "recipe for disaster" especially if you don't connect the dots as to why.

Answer (score 0):

even tho this is an old post, I found it inspiring to fix a problem we were facing:
after several migrations performed on the development side and tested in staging, the devops asked the dev team to remove migrations from the repository by adding it to the .gitignore (due to some imncompatibility between the local sqlite and the devops staging environment using MariaDB - this was not a best practice and opposite to what is reccomended by django guide workflow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/ ).
The devops team would run the makemigrations and migrate on the staging environment and all would be fine. however the dev team didn't reset the migrations folder each time, hence there were building up changes in the local dev migrations that were not replicated in staging. during the staging this was not an issue since the devops team could reset the staging database without consequences. however after the production was set and production data was present, the migrations and database could not be synced the same way.

To solve, we had to review our devops guideline. We keep the migrations from dev in the repository, solving all MariaDB concerns during development (ie, limits of charfields etc). Eventually the migrations can be squashed from dev.

to workaround the wrong sync in the production database we faked all the migrations then removed from the database django_migrations table, the migrations that were including the latest schema changes (in stead of rollback as those schema were not applied hence would have given an error). At this stage the database and the migrations were in sync and only the latest migrations had to be applied.
useful commands:

```
python manage.py showmigrations
./manage.py makemigrations # ==> no changes deteceted
./manage.py migrate --fake # ==> this will mark all migrations in the django_migrations table
# delete from the DB the django_migrations of 'new' model changes that aren't in the database
./manage.py migrate # ==> so to apply the latest schema updates.
```